# 0 KB output file after decryption

Tags: batch-file, gnupg, pgp

I'm able to decrypt the file using GNUPG or Kleopatra (gpg4win) manually, however when I run this through batch I get the 0 KB output, any reason why? below is my code;

```
@echo off
set LOGFILE=Log.log
call :LOG > %LOGFILE%
exit
:LOG

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "secret=mypassword"

set datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%

set origPath=D:\Encrypted\
set origFile=my_test_file
set origExt=.PGP
set origCompleteFile=%origPath%%origFile%%datestamp%%origExt%

set destPath=D:\Encrypted\
set destFile=my_test_file_ddmmyyyy
set destExt=.csv
set destCompleteFile=%destPath%%destFile%%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%%destExt%

set ctaFolder=N:\Test\

echo Decrypt file : "%origCompleteFile%"
echo Save decrypted file in : "%destCompleteFile%"

rem decrypt CTA File
gpg --batch --passphrase "%secret%" --decrypt "%origCompleteFile%" > "%destCompleteFile%"

rem copy to CTA folder in .54
xcopy /s/y "%destCompleteFile%" "%ctaFolder%"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to redirect binary data into a file. The Windows command line interface is designed for text data and not for binary data. And additionally everything output by the commands below `:LOG` to **stdout** is redirected to file `Log.log` by your batch file.

The [GPG manual](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.html) explains all available command line options of this console application.

It is explained for option `--decrypt` that the decrypted data is written to handle **stdout** or to a file specified after option `--output`.

So the solution is simply using additionally the option `--output` instead of a redirection of **stdout** to a file.

```
gpg --batch --passphrase "%secret%" --output "%destCompleteFile%" --decrypt "%origCompleteFile%"
```

The entire batch code could be optimized to this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "secret=mypassword"

rem Get current date in format YYYYMMDD for usage in file name (DDMMYYYY commented out).
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "LocalDateTime=%%I"
rem set "FileNameDate=%LocalDateTime:~6,2%%LocalDateTime:~4,2%%LocalDateTime:~0,4%"
set "FileNameDate=%LocalDateTime:~0,8%"

set "origPath=D:\Encrypted\"
set "origFile=my_test_file_"
set "origExt=.csv.gpg"
set "origCompleteFile=%origPath%%origFile%%FileNameDate%%origExt%"

set "destPath=D:\Encrypted\"
set "destFile=my_test_file_"
set "destExt=.csv"
set "destCompleteFile=%destPath%%destFile%%FileNameDate%%destExt%"

set "ctaFolder=N:\Test\"

echo Decrypt file: "%origCompleteFile%"
echo Save decrypted file in: "%destCompleteFile%"

rem Decrypt CTA file
gpg --batch --passphrase "%secret%" --output "%destCompleteFile%" --decrypt "%origCompleteFile%"

rem Copy to CTA folder in .54
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%destCompleteFile%" "%ctaFolder%" /Q /Y >nul
endlocal
```

It would be of course possible to generate the decrypted file directly in the folder defined by environment variable `ctaFolder`.